# pdf file failed to download from web page

Tags: html, href

This is after the checkout component. I linked the `href` manually to the pdf file that created on the server side after checkout, the pdf file is fine, it opens perfectly, but when I try to download it on client side it fails...

[image]

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Your purchase was successful!</h3>
    <h4>
      To download your invoice,
      <a
        href="/../server/Inovice.pdf"
        download="Inovice.pdf"
      >
        click here</a
      >.
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited!
The problem was with my `/` at the start of the url
the right one is

```
 href="../server/Inovice.pdf"
```

Comment: what do your dev tools say? is that url right? the `/` and `..` seem to conflict

Comment: On the href I just navigate manually to the folder and click on the file that I want the user will download, but it just don't work...

Comment: @KJ If I understand what your saying,  so the pdf file created before the clicking on the download file.

Comment: The problem is in the `href`. What is `/../`? Are you sure the path you're trying to access even exists? Do you have a server that produces the PDF, and is it up?

Comment: @ShrihanKumarPadhy I have 2 folders, one for the Client side (angular) , and one for the Server (nodeJS), the pdf file is located at the server side. When I am doing `/../ `, so it's taking me one folder back to the server side. And yes I have server that produces my PDF, and the PDF is work perfectly.

Comment: @BarJa you should read up on how relative paths work in web

Comment: Thanks you all for the help , It's work now , the problem was really the `/` on the beginning of the `href`.

Comment: @BarJa It is recommended to write the solution as an Answer below and click the Checkmark to accept it, so that other people may find this helpful.